# Find the radius and area of the figure

Tags: geometry

> A wire of $32\,\mathrm{cm}$ in length is bent into the figure given below. $APD$ is a semicircle and $AB=BC=CD$. Find the radius and area of the circle.

Answer: Radius${}=3.5\mathrm{cm}$ and Area${}=68.25\mathrm{cm}^2$

I tried using $\pi r+ 2r$ to find the perimeter of the semicircle and $4r^2$ for the three sides of the square (dotted line is not counted in perimeter) and got
$\pi r+ 2r + 4r^2= 32$, but I'm not getting the answer. Please help! Let me know if my logic is wrong.

[image]

Comment: The quantity $4r^2$ represents the area of $ABCD$, not its perimeter.

Comment: Oh. Didn't realize that. I assumed perimeter is basically the addition of all three sides? I don't know. Thanks for correcting!  What do I use for perimeter?

Comment: Each side of the rectangle has side length $2r$.  Since we have three sides, its perimeter is $3 \cdot 2r = 6r$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if the radius is $\require{color}r$, then the perimeter is $\pi r+\textcolor{red}{6}r=32$.

Comment: Perimeter of the entire figure? How'd you derive that?

Comment: Oh wait. Gotcha...

Comment: @HarleenFangirlDhunda There are three sides of the square to count and the semicircle.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I'll try that!